# Infinite loop bash script won't run on startup but runs when started manually

Tags: bash, shell-script, bluetooth

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

USER_HOME=$(eval echo ~${SUDO_USER})
BLUETOOTH_THERMOMETER_MAC="00:00:00:00:00:00"

function calc_value() {
    hex_temp1=$1
    hex_temp2=$2
    hex_temp1_trimmed=`echo $hex_temp1`
    hex_temp2_trimmed=`echo $hex_temp2`
    hextemp=$( echo "${hex_temp2_trimmed}${hex_temp1_trimmed}" )
    dectemp=$( echo $((16#$hextemp)) )
    dectemp_double=$( echo ${dectemp})
    b=16
    echo "$(echo "$dectemp $b" | awk '{print $1 / $2}')"

}

while true
do
    checker_trimmed="..^.......*=..#."
    while [ ${#out} -lt 1 ] || [ "$chrlen" != 289 ] || [ "$checker_trimmed" == "..^.......*=..#." ] || [ "$checker_trimmed" == "..^.......*=...." ] || [ "$checker_trimmed" == "..^............." ]
    do
        bluetoothctl_out=$( { printf 'scan on\n\n' ; sleep 10 ; printf 'quit \n\n' ; } | bluetoothctl)
        out=$( echo "$bluetoothctl_out" | grep -A 2 "Device $BLUETOOTH_THERMOMETER_MAC ManufacturerData Value:")
        chrlen=${#out}
        checker=$(echo "$out" | cut -d ' ' -f 21)
        checker_trimmed=`echo $checker`
        hex_temp1=$(echo "$out" | cut -d ' ' -f 14)
        hex_temp2=$(echo "$out" | cut -d ' ' -f 15)
        hex_hum1=$(echo "$out" | cut -d ' ' -f 16)
        hex_hum2=$(echo "$out" | cut -d ' ' -f 17)
        room_temp=$(echo $(calc_value $hex_temp1 $hex_temp2) | awk '{printf("%0.1f",$1)}')
        room_hum=$(echo $(calc_value $hex_hum1 $hex_hum2) | awk '{printf("%0.1f",$1)}')
    done
    echo "$(date);${room_temp}°C;${room_hum}%" >> "$USER_HOME/test.txt"
    sleep 10
done
```

It reads the BLE packets from bluetooth thermometer, parses them and writes them to the file test.txt specified in my home directory. The script runs untill the process is manually killed (infinite loop).

**Problem:**

If I start it manually i.e. through terminal it works fine (it writes the output in test.txt), but when I start it through startup applications in GNOME or put it in `/etc/init.d` it doesn't output anything.

I am sure the script is started because when I run `ps aux` and search for it is says that it is running but it won't write anything the specified file -> `>> "$USER_HOME/test.txt"`

Can you help me find out what is going on?

Comment: Do you run it with `sudo` in each case?

Comment: In the case that it seems not to work, how are you starting it? Have you looked in root's home directory for your log file? Have you looked in `/` itself for your log file?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I don't know how it is started, since I just select the file through gnome startup applications or I just put the script into `/etc/init.d`, but to avoid any problems in case script is run with `sudo` I have `eval echo ~${SUDO_USER}` which finds mine home directory

Comment: @roaima there is no file in `/` only in my home directory. I have made sure it saves in my home directory with `eval echo ~${SUDO_USER}` but it seems like the path is not the problem

Comment: What exactly do you have to start it from `/etc/init.d`?

Comment: Why not `echo $USER_HOME > /var/tmp/debugscript` to double-check?

Comment: @berndbausch I just checked, and yes it does output the correct home directory. Weirdly it outputs it there but doesn't in the file I specified inside of my directory

Comment: @roaima I just put the script there and it runs it on startup

Comment: Brute-force: `sudo find / -name test.txt`. And, for test purposes, replace $USER_HOME with a constant such as `/var/tmp`.

Comment: @berndbausch `sudo find / -name test.txt` no test.txt file in my root. Only the one that I created in home. When I replaced the $USER_HOME with `/var/tmp` it does output it there. It seem that it outputs only in root directory and doesn't want to output it in home directory

Comment: Does $USER_HOME/test.txt have incompatible permissions? Or is otherwise not writable? What happens if you remove it (or move it)?

Comment: If you have literally placed your script in `/etc/init.d` then I'm amazed your system boots, as that's not how the scripts there are expected to work. Furthermore there will be no `sudo` involved, so `${SUDO_USER}` will be empty, and `~` will simply map to root's home directory

Comment: Since you don't check if `$USER_HOME` is valid,  you could be putting your file anywhere. Also, what's `$PWD`?

Comment: While it's running, `sudo lsof | grep test.txt` will show where the file is being written.